# Represent the colour of a bit field

Tags: colors, visualization, data-visualization, bit-fields

Can anyone show me a (language agnostic) way to assign a colour value to a bit field so that comparatively similar bit fields have a similar colour to each other. So for example

```
01100111
```

And

```
01110111
```

Are close in colour relatively. But

```
11011001
```

Is further away

By "further away"  I mean distant in hue, saturation, brightness, etc...

If we have an array of all the bit fields then it would be possible to compare them all then produce a set of colours. But what if we don't know and we want one bit field to always be represented by one colour?

Or else we could pre compute all possible colour values for a given number if bits. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, because (essentially) there are only 2 dimensions to your perceived color space, while treating the bits independently as you suggest makes a separate dimension for each bit.

Comment: I thought colour was a one dimensional property?

Comment: No - think of it as frequency (the color value) versus energy (brightness).  PuTTY has a color-selection dialog that helps to see this.  [http://fastdot.com/resources/change-the-appearance-of-putty/] page with screenshot.

Comment: What about if we pre-compute every possible combination for N bits? I figure the O complexity is going to be O(2^N).

Comment: That won't address the question which you asked (enumerating the possibilities will not provide a way of making them comparable as requested).

Comment: Is it because there needs to be >=N dimensions for the colour?

Comment: I suppose that is a way of looking at it.  For instance, considering the RGB representation of a color, that gives 3 dimensions.  A particular color is some point in the (positive values only!) first octant.  A function to measure "similar" colors would be one-dimensional (since it is measuring closeness).  So it couldn't match all of the possibilities.